# Loading a dynamic library at run-time yields inconsistent and unexpected results, missing symbols and empty PLT entries. Why?

Tags: c, gcc, ld, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading

I've been fighting with this problem for quite some time, and I've been unable to find a solution or even an explanation for it. So sorry if the question is long, but bear with me as I just want to make it 100% clear in the hopes that someone more experienced than me will be able to figure it out.

<sup>I'm keeping the C syntax highlight on for all snippets because it makes them a little bit clearer even if not really correct.</sup>

### What I want to do

I have a C program which uses some functions from a dynamic library (`libzip`). Here it is boiled down to a minimal reproducible example (it basically does nothing, but it works just fine):

```
#include <zip.h>

int main(void) {
    int err;
    zip_t *myzip;

    myzip = zip_open("myzip.zip", ZIP_CREATE | ZIP_TRUNCATE, &err);
    if (myzip == NULL)
        return 1;

    zip_close(myzip);

    return 0;
}
```

Normally, to compile it, I would simply do:

```
gcc -c prog.c
gcc -o prog prog.o -lzip
```

This creates, as expected, an ELF which requires `libzip` to run:

```
$ ldd prog
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdafb53000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f81eedc7000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f81ef780000)
libzip.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip.so.4 (0x00007f81ef166000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f81eebad000)
```

<sup>(`libz` is just a dependency of `libzip`)</sup>

What I *really* want to do though, is to **load the library myself using `dlopen()`**. Pretty simple task, no? Well yes, or at least I thought.

To achieve this, I should just need to call `dlopen` and let the loader do its job:

```
#include <zip.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(void) {
    void *lib;
    int err;
    zip_t *myzip;

    lib = dlopen("libzip.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if (lib == NULL)
        return 1;

    myzip = zip_open("myzip.zip", ZIP_CREATE | ZIP_TRUNCATE, &err);
    if (myzip == NULL)
        return 1;

    zip_close(myzip);

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, since I want to *manually* load the library myself, I will not link it this time:

```
# Create prog.o
gcc -c prog.c

# Do a dry-run just to make sure all symbols are resolved
gcc -o /dev/null prog.o -ldl -lzip

# Now recompile only with libdl
gcc -o prog prog.o -ldl -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files
```

The flag `--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files` tells `ld` to not worry about my `prog.o` having unresolved symbols at link time (I want to take care of that myself at runtime).

### The problem

The above *Should Just Work™*, and indeed it does seem to... but I have two machines, and being the pedantic nerd I am I just thought "well, better make sure and compile it on both of them".

#### First machine

x86-64, Linux 4.9, Debian 9, `gcc` 6.3.0, `ld` 2.28. Here **everything works as expected**.

I can clearly see that the symbols are there:

```
$ readelf --dyn-syms prog

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 15 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTab
     2: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
     3: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
===> 4: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND zip_close
     5: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND dlopen@GLIBC_2.2.5 (3)
===> 6: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND zip_open
     7: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _Jv_RegisterClasses
     8: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
     9: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
    10: 0000000000201040     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 _edata
    11: 0000000000201048     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   26 _end
    12: 0000000000201040     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   26 __bss_start
    13: 00000000000006a0     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 _init
    14: 0000000000000924     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 _fini
```

The PLT entries are also there as expected and look fine:

```
$ objdump -j .plt -M intel -d prog

Disassembly of section .plt:

00000000000006c0 <.plt>:
 6c0:   ff 35 42 09 20 00       push   QWORD PTR [rip+0x200942]        # 201008 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
 6c6:   ff 25 44 09 20 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x200944]        # 201010 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
 6cc:   0f 1f 40 00             nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]

00000000000006d0 <zip_close@plt>:
 6d0:   ff 25 42 09 20 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x200942]        # 201018 <zip_close>
 6d6:   68 00 00 00 00          push   0x0
 6db:   e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmp    6c0 <.plt>

00000000000006e0 <dlopen@plt>:
 6e0:   ff 25 3a 09 20 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x20093a]        # 201020 <dlopen@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 6e6:   68 01 00 00 00          push   0x1
 6eb:   e9 d0 ff ff ff          jmp    6c0 <.plt>

00000000000006f0 <zip_open@plt>:
 6f0:   ff 25 32 09 20 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x200932]        # 201028 <zip_open>
 6f6:   68 02 00 00 00          push   0x2
 6fb:   e9 c0 ff ff ff          jmp    6c0 <.plt>
```

And the program runs without any problem:

```
$ ./prog
$ echo $?
0
```

Even looking inside it with a debugger I can clearly see the symbols getting correctly resolved like any normal dynamic symbol:

```
0x55555555479b <main+43>                       lea    rax, [rbp - 0x14]
0x55555555479f <main+47>                       mov    rdx, rax
0x5555555547a2 <main+50>                       mov    esi, 9
0x5555555547a7 <main+55>                       lea    rdi, [rip + 0xc0] <0x7ffff7ffd948>
0x5555555547ae <main+62>                       call   zip_open@plt <0x555555554620>
 |
 v ### PLT entry:
0x555555554620 <zip_open@plt>                  jmp    qword ptr [rip + 0x200a02] <0x555555755028>
 |
 v 
0x555555554626 <zip_open@plt+6>                push   2
0x55555555462b <zip_open@plt+11>               jmp    0x5555555545f0
 |
 v ### PLT stub:
0x5555555545f0                                 push   qword ptr [rip + 0x200a12] <0x555555755008>
0x5555555545f6                                 jmp    qword ptr [rip + 0x200a14] <0x7ffff7def0d0>
 |
 v ### Symbol gets correctly resolved
0x7ffff7def0d0 <_dl_runtime_resolve_fxsave>    push   rbx
0x7ffff7def0d1 <_dl_runtime_resolve_fxsave+1>  mov    rbx, rsp
0x7ffff7def0d4 <_dl_runtime_resolve_fxsave+4>  and    rsp, 0xfffffffffffffff0
0x7ffff7def0d8 <_dl_runtime_resolve_fxsave+8>  sub    rsp, 0x240
```

### Second machine

x86-64, Linux 4.15, Ubuntu 18.04, `gcc` 7.4, `ld` 2.30. Here, **something really strange is going on**.

Compilation doesn't yield any warning or error, *but* I do not see the symbols:

```
$ readelf --dyn-syms prog

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 7 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTab
     2: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
     3: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
     4: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND dlopen@GLIBC_2.2.5 (3)
     5: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
     6: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
```

The PLT entries *are there*, but they are filled with zeroes, and aren't even recognized by `objdump`:

```
$ objdump -j .plt -M intel -d prog

Disassembly of section .plt:

0000000000000560 <.plt>:
 560:   ff 35 4a 0a 20 00       push   QWORD PTR [rip+0x200a4a]        # 200fb0 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
 566:   ff 25 4c 0a 20 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x200a4c]        # 200fb8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
 56c:   0f 1f 40 00             nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
    ...

#   ^^^
# Here, these three dots are actually hiding another 0x10+ bytes filled of 0x0
# zip_close@plt should be here instead...

0000000000000580 <dlopen@plt>:
 580:   ff 25 42 0a 20 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x200a42]        # 200fc8 <dlopen@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 586:   68 00 00 00 00          push   0x0
 58b:   e9 d0 ff ff ff          jmp    560 <.plt>
    ...

#   ^^^
# Here, these three dots are actually hiding another 0x10+ bytes filled of 0x0
# zip_open@plt should be here instead...
```

When the program is run, `dlopen()` works fine and loads `libzip` into memory, but then when `zip_open()` gets called, it just generates a segmentation fault:

```
$ ./prog
Segmentation fault (code dumped)
```

Taking a look with a debugger, the issue is even more obvious (in case it wasn't already obvious enough). The PLT entries filled with zeroes just end up decoding to a bunch of `add` instructions dereferencing `rax`, which contains an invalid address and makes the program segfault and die:

```
0x5555555546e5 <main+43>               lea    rax, [rbp - 0x14]
0x5555555546e9 <main+47>               mov    rdx, rax
0x5555555546ec <main+50>               mov    esi, 9
0x5555555546f1 <main+55>               lea    rdi, [rip + 0xc6]
0x5555555546f8 <main+62>               call   dlopen@plt+16 <0x555555554590>
 |
 v ### Broken PLT enrty (all 0x0, will cause a segfault):
0x555555554590 <dlopen@plt+16>         add    byte ptr [rax], al
0x555555554592 <dlopen@plt+18>         add    byte ptr [rax], al
0x555555554594 <dlopen@plt+20>         add    byte ptr [rax], al
0x555555554596 <dlopen@plt+22>         add    byte ptr [rax], al
0x555555554598 <dlopen@plt+24>         add    byte ptr [rax], al
0x55555555459a <dlopen@plt+26>         add    byte ptr [rax], al
0x55555555459c <dlopen@plt+28>         add    byte ptr [rax], al
0x55555555459e <dlopen@plt+30>         add    byte ptr [rax], al
   ### Next PLT entry...
0x5555555545a0 <__cxa_finalize@plt>    jmp    qword ptr [rip + 0x200a52] <0x7ffff7823520>
 |
 v
0x7ffff7823520 <__cxa_finalize>        push   r15
0x7ffff7823522 <__cxa_finalize+2>      push   r14
```

### Questions

1. So, first of all... why is this happening?
2. I thought that this was supposed to work, isn't it? If not, why? And why only on one of the two machines?
3. But most importantly: **how can I fix this**?

For question 3 I want to emphasize that the whole point of this is that I want to load the library myself, without linking it, so please refrain from just commenting that this is bad practice, or whatever else.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica of course you have no issue there, you just linked the library (`-lzip`) :), the whold point of my question is that I *do not* want to link it.

Comment: Yikes my bad, I through that in out of habit -- and of course it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The above Should Just Work™, and indeed it does seem to...

No, it should not, and if it appears to, that's more of an accident. In general, using `--unresolved-symbols=...` is a really bad idea™, and will almost never do what you want.

The solution is trivial: you just need to look up `zip_open` and `zip_close`, like so:

```
int main(void) {
    void *lib;
    zip_t *p_open(const char *, int, int *);
    void *p_close(zip_t*);
    int err;
    zip_t *myzip;

    lib = dlopen("libzip.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if (lib == NULL)
        return 1;

    p_open = (zip_t(*)(const char *, int, int *))dlsym(lib, "zip_open");
    if (p_open == NULL)
        return 1;
    p_close = (void(*)(zip_t*))dlsym(lib, "zip_close");
    if (p_close == NULL)
        return 1;

    myzip = p_open("myzip.zip", ZIP_CREATE | ZIP_TRUNCATE, &err);
    if (myzip == NULL)
        return 1;

    p_close(myzip);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why does it "almost never do what you want"? Why shouldn't the loader just make the symbols available for global resolution without the need to manually call dlsym? That's basically what RTLD_GLOBAL is there for, isn't it? Also, this requires hardcoding the signature of all the functions I'm going to use (which seems quite unfeasible, the actual program is way larger), isn't there any other method that I could use?

Comment: Another problem about hardcoding the signatures is that if the library has different signatures on different architectures (the ultimate goal would be to make this compatible with every Linux system supporting libzip) this just breaks everything because it assumes the wrong signature. I'm not 100% sure about this though. Does what I'm saying make sense? I would prefer a simpler/more portable/more automated option.

Comment: Why would the signature be different? It's a documented part of the library's API.

Comment: `RTLD_GLOBAL` makes the symbols of the loaded library available for use in resolving symbols for future `dlopen` calls, or `dlsym` calls on the global namespace (as opposed to a particular library). It **does not** redefine existing symbols or magically make unresolved ones in already-relocated code/data now resolve to the new definitions.

Comment: In theory, the link-time linker and the dynamic linker, working together, *could* make these calls work, if they go through the PLT, but that'd highly target-dependent. It fundamentally couldn't make the calls work if they went through function pointers in initialized global data, since it can't tell if the program has already seen the old (unresolved) value of the data or written something else over top of it already. And since this kind of hack can't work in general, it doesn't make sense to "support it for the cases it happens to work on, for implementation-detail reasons".

Comment: @R.. well I guess you're right about the signatures. My concern is that even if they are part of the API, the API itself could change and the explicit cast would just hide the problem and generate a faulty executable. Should I not be concerned about this? -- As per `RTLD_GLOBAL`, I just re-read the man page, you're right, that's its only purpose indeed.

Comment: Even if you don't use `dlopen` but link directly to the shared library, a future version of the library *could* change the signature. This would be ABI-breaking, but nothing can automatically detect it. As a responsible library provider, you don't do that. You either introduce new function names for the incompatible interface, or introduce a new major library version or name, or use some kind of versioning (ideally *not* ELF symbol versioning since that wrongly binds to the version seen at link time rather than to the version whose headers you compiled against).

Comment: So anyway, regardless of whether you `dlopen` or link directly, there are still the same risks of dangerous mismatch if the library author does something irresponsible and changes it out from under you.

Comment: @R.. Of course, but if I don't dlopen and the API changes then I will get a compilation error, that's what I'm saying. I guess what you're saying makes a lot of sense though, and it's basically a non-problem, I'm worrying to much. Thank you for the great explanations.

Comment: You'll get a compilation error at the time you compile, if it mismatches at the time you compile. You won't get one at runtime (or even link-time, if that's later than compile-time, e.g. if the affected code is in an archive (.a) library) if the shared library gets changed later.

Comment: @R.. "the link-time linker and the dynamic linker, working together, could make these calls work" - check the other answer for a variation of this approach which does not require changes in tools.

Answer (score 2):

To add to EmployedRussian's answer, you can achieve what you need with the help of [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so) tool. It would generate stubs for all library symbols (e.g. `zip_open`) which would call `dlopen`/`dlsym` internally and forward calls from your program to shared library:

```
$ gcc -c prog.c
$ implib-gen.py path/to/libzip.so
$ gcc -o prog prog.o libzip.tramp.S libzip.init.c -ldl
```

(note that you no longer need fancy linker flags and linker dry runs).

As a side note what you are trying to do is called delayed loading and is a [standard feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=vs-2019) of Windows DLLS.